# how to make edit and delete button visible or invisible based on user role in table action column?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

> I am using ajax for showing doctor list in my index.blade.php file.But
> i want to show edit and delete button only for admin user rest users
> can not see the edit or delete button in index.blade.phpBut i dont
> understand who to do it on the following ajax portion.

```
@section('js')
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 fetch_doctor_data();

 function fetch_doctor_data(query = '')
 {
 
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{route('search.doctor')}}",
   method:"GET",
   data:{'query':query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    var role=$('#role').val();
    var output = '';
    if(data.data.length > 0)
    {
     for(var count = 0; count < data.data.length; count++)
     {
     
      output += '<tr>';
      output += '<td class="center"><img src="'+data.data[count].image+'" style="width:40px;height:40px;"/></td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].name+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].department.name+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].email+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].mobile+'</td>';
      output += '<td>'+data.data[count].status+'</td>';
      output += '<td><a class="btn btn-info" href="doctors/'+data.data[count].id+'"><i class="fas fa-eye">View</i></a><a style="margin-left:3px;" class="btn btn-primary" href="doctors/'+data.data[count].id+'/edit"><i class="fas fa-edit">Edit</i></a><button style="margin-left:3px;" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="'+data.data[count].id+'" data-id="'+data.data[count].id+'"><i class="fas fa-trash">Delete</i></button></td>';


    
      output += '</tr>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     output += '<tr>';
     output += '<td colspan="8" style="text-align:center">No Data Found</td>';
     output += '</tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(output);
   }
   
  })
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_doctor_data(query);
 });

});
</script>
  
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Sure You secure the routes by middlewares, in the javascript you can use the laravel blade if , Ex : @if($user->able('delete')) @endif, and put the codes between the if.

ex :

```
@if($user->able('delete')) alert('he can delete'); @endif
```